# rpi nfc tag emulation

Tags: pi-3, nfc

I am looking for a NFC device which can work with rpi (3B) and is able to emulate card. NFC devices are super confusing world. I tried several NFC devices with PN532 controller and all of them so far were not able to emulate cards. This info is usually buried deep in documentation or it is not there at all and you find one small comment after days of searching on some forgotten forum. Now I am using Waveshare PN532 NFC HAT and this one should be able to emulate cards. But I found one comment somewhere on 1 very old looking website that it cannot, so again I can't be sure.

I was able to get this device working with HCE but not to emulate card. According to PN532 documentation I am supposed to call TgInitAsTarget command, which should be acknowledged by ACK and return Mode + InitiatorCommand. After this I should call TgGetData to receive data from initiator (the NFC scanner - in my case mobile phone). I get to the point of ACK but I never get Mode + InitiatorCommand response so calling TgGetData doesn't do anything as well.

I have 2 questions. Can this device emulate cards? And if not does anyone have practical experience with device that can? Please don't just add links to devices googled on the web which state that they can emulate cards - the description is usually just wrong.

I am adding wiki page of the device I am using https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/PN532_NFC_HAT

Comment: I googled and found one guy saying that he solved the problem by buying a new module: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35894589/send-tginitastarget-command-to-pn532-elehouse-module-get-ack-frame-back-but-l. Instead of buying a new module, perhaps you can lower the baud rate from 424kb to say 9.6kb

Comment: Thank you for response. Unluckily he didn't say which module he bought. There are many modules with PN532 and each has different specs. I asked him in the comments. Not sure why should different bound rate help but I can try

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck to your project. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I used the SCM Micro SCL3711 reader under Linux with libnfc (NFC Forum Type 2 Tag) and nfcpy (NFC Forum Type 3 Tag) to emulate NDEF Tags